# Do I have to register and get a key from Google to be able to have a "login with Google"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I was using omniauth to let my users "login with" google, yahoo, etc.

But all of a sudden it stopped working. I still can see the user data being sent to the server through the URL, but omniauth isn't accepting it. It says 'invalid credentials' for some reason.

This was my configuration:

```
config.omniauth :open_id, :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/srv/www/myapp/tmp'), :name => 'google', :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id', :require => 'omniauth-openid'
```

But now I see there is also a google strategy I can use (instead of open-id) here: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/List-of-Strategies

It requires a KEY though, so now I'm confused. Why does google accept many strategies? Which should I be using?

Should my open-id strategy still work? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

If you recently updated the version of the Omniauth gem you're using, you might no longer have the gems you need installed. They split out the different providers into their own gems.

See https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/451 for discussion on the issue.

Information about Google OAuth2 that might prove helpful: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

Comment: I'm trying to set up the new gems, but no success so far. Tell me if I'm wrong: Instead of gem 'omniauth-openid', it should now be 'oa-openid'? I can't see any updates in their docs: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-openid.

Comment: I'm getting this for the new gem 'oa-openid': Received wrong number of arguments. [:open_id]